# how to use string values ​in x-axis of line graph d3.js v3.5.6

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to place a string on the x axis of a line graph, initially the x axis is a date variable, but now I must add a string that differentiates me if it is morning 'AM', afternoon 'PM' or night 'ZM' .
I am using nvd3 v1.8.1 with angularjs. The initial code is as follows

```
tchart.xAxis
    // Chart x-axis settings
    .axisLabel('Muestras')
    .tickFormat( function(d){
                        return d3.time.format('%y-%m-%d %p')
                                    (Utils.utcDateToLocalDate(d))
                    });

        chart.xScale(d3.time.scale.utc());
        tchart.yAxis // Chart y-axis settings
        .axisLabel('Temperatura').tickFormat(
        d3.format('.02f'));

        var tdata = getData('temperatura');

        d3.select('#temperatureChart svg').datum(tdata).call(tchart);


        var getData = function(_prop) {
                var _data = [];

                $scope.registros.forEach(function(_item, _index) {
                        var _cfecha = _item.fecha.split('-');
                        var _fecha = new Date(Date.UTC(
                                    parseInt(_cfecha[0]),
                                    parseInt(_cfecha[1]),
                                    parseInt(_cfecha[2]),
                                    (_item.horario === 'AM') ? 1: 13,0, 0));
                        _data.push({
                            x : _fecha,
                            y : _item[_prop]
                        });
                });

                return [ {
                    values : _data,
                    key : _prop,
                    color : '#ff7f0e'
                } ];
    };
```

With which I obtain the result of graph follow.

[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCR2I.png)

Then I increased a variable of 'label' in the data to use them in thickformat, but not all the values ​​are shown in the graph2

```
//fill data array
_data.push({
    x : _fecha,
    y : _item[_prop],
    label : _lfecha
});

//tchar.xAxis
.tickFormat(function(d,i) { 
    return tdata[0].values[i].label;
}
```

[graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mxf2.png)

I also used an ordinal scale with the values ​​of the data matrix, but only shows the start day and the end day, the other values ​​are omitted (graph3)

```
var x = d3.extent(tdata[0].values, function(d) { console.log(d); return d.label; });

tchart.xScale(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(x));
```

[grahp3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b07nq.png)

The result I expect is the same as the first graphic but the axis labels allow me to concatenate the date with the abbreviations AM-PM-ZM

Comment: Hi Victor. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you add some more code and maybe add some sample data for review. It would be even better if you could create and example on blockbuilder.org or jsfiddle or some similar site, where we can see the result and visualize the output you desire.

Comment: Hello @Coola, thanks for answering, I edited the question with more details about the problem